# Http Post file to server from Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, http, server, http-post

I'm making a Windows Application that need to make a HTTP post to my Server. In my .NET MVC application i use this code:

```
Html.BeginForm("Index","UploadData",           
                            FormMethod.Post,
                            new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "contact-form", id = "frmUploadData" })
```

My question is how do i post a File from my computer to the server from a windows forms application?

I have tried to use, this method, but i am not sure how to call it correctly:

```
 public static void HttpUploadFile(string url, string file, string paramName, string contentType, NameValueCollection nvc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Uploading {0} to {1}", file, url));
        string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

        HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        wr.Method = "POST";
        wr.KeepAlive = true;
        wr.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream();

        string formdataTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n{1}";
        foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
        {
            rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
            string formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, key, nvc[key]);
            byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
            rs.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);
        }
        rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

        string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n";
        string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, paramName, file, contentType);
        byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
        rs.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);

        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            rs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        fileStream.Close();

        byte[] trailer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
        rs.Write(trailer, 0, trailer.Length);
        rs.Close();

        WebResponse wresp = null;
        try
        {
            wresp = wr.GetResponse();
            Stream stream2 = wresp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("File uploaded, server response is: {0}", reader2.ReadToEnd()));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error uploading file", ex);
            if (wresp != null)
            {
                wresp.Close();
                wresp = null;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            wr = null;
        }
    }
```

Not sure if i am calling it correctly, i get a 404 error when i try to call this method:

```
    public static void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
        nvc.Add("id", "frmUploadData");
        HttpUploadFile("http://classicraider.com/UploadData",
             @e.FullPath, "file", "lua", nvc);
        Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);

    }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow , please share some code you have tried so far.
You mean post to the server an uploaded file?

Comment: @Mohameed, i just posted the code i have tried, but i am not sure how to make it work correctly...

Comment: what is `@e.fullpath` value? is this where your file located?

Comment: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\World of Warcraft\\_classic_\\WTF\\Account\\401316903#1\\SavedVariables\\ClassicRaiderProfile.lua"

Comment: i suggest try it first with this parameter as `filepath` :
@"C:\ClassicRaiderProfile.lua"
put your file in your drive c root

Comment: I got it working now, i had to use             nvc.Add("id", "file");
            nvc.Add("class", "upload-input");

Comment: glad to hear it . nice! :)